# Improve Python (.exe) startup time

Tags: python, pytorch, pyinstaller, python-3.9, yolov5

I created an exe with the PyInstaller. As soon as I enable the `--onefile` flag. The exe needs several minutes to start. When I build the application with the `--onedir` flag, the exe launches immediately after launch. In order to distribute the application better, it is important for me that the exe is created with the --onefile flag.

My problem can be reproduced with the following two scripts.

In `main.py` I only import the torch module, because the problems only occur with this module.

```
#main.py
print("Test1")
import torch
print("Test2")
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
print("Test3")
```

I generate the exe with the `setup.py` file.

```
#setup.py
import PyInstaller.__main__
import pyinstaller_versionfile

PyInstaller.__main__.run([
    'main.py',
    '--onefile',
    '--name=Object Detection',
    '--console',
])
```

Alternatively, the exe can also be generated using the Powershell command.

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --name "Object Detection"
```

So my question is what can be done to make the application start faster? What is the specific cause of the problem?

By excluding the module `--exclude-module=torch` the application also starts immediately,
but that's not my goal.

Answer (score 3):

Pyinstaller **--onefile** mode has to unpack all libraries before starting in a temporary directory, when you use **--onedir** they are already there. The problem is noticeable with big libraries like PyTorch ...

Comment: Is there a workaround other than using `--onedir`?

Comment: Is there perhaps a better alternative to Pyinstaller? Maybe I can also outsource the Pytorch module? Or convert my `.pt`-model  into a `.onnx`-model and then load it with opencv?!

Comment: There may be some workarounds , but you are better using a language that is not interpreted like C/C++ instead if you want a clean executable.

Comment: This is problematic because I implemented my entire project in Python.

Comment: Is there any way to extract --onefile executable into permanent folder (not temporary every time)?